# How to move from one tab to another in TabController in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tabs

In my application i have TabBarView controller , in that i have 4 tabs and in 3rd tab i have buttons when click on button i need to go 1 tab.Please can any one help me.
Here my code is:

```
    [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Thanking in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `selectedIndex` of the tab bar controller will change the selected tab (and associated view controller). You can also set `selectedViewController` if that is easier based on your current code / configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Please try one of these solutions:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

or

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

just set SelectedIndex of `tabBarViewController` to `0` like bellow..

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```